# issue to use sonarqube and vssonar extension

Tags: sonarqube

I have install vssonar extension on visual studio 2012, I want to test my code using sonarqube from the visual studio but getting difficulty for the same, I am not able to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the vssonarextension has limited support for 2012. Only really old versions of SQ are supported.  And new features have not been release for 2012 since there are almost no downloads.